# Connect locahost PHP server to webhost

Tags: javascript, php, electron

Actualy, I'm making an app in Electron and i use ELECTRON-4-PHP because idk other back-end langage.
And if i want to put my app online, how can i do ?
Actualy the server is setup by this:

```
const PHPServer = require('php-server-manager');

const server = new PHPServer({
  php: "php/php.exe", // <==== ADDED
  host:"localhost",
  port:8000,
  directory: __dirname,
  directives: {
  display_errors: 1,
  expose_php: 1
```

So whitch port can i use ?
Actualy when i run the app after put the ip of the server,
that displat: "error: failed listen on *my server ip*
witch path for the php.exe and witch directory, please its the first time i a server online, im lost ‍♂️
Thanks you so mutch

Comment: PHP defaults to port `80` I believe. Also, if you're using Electron, then you know Javascript and you can use NodeJS as a backend

Comment: thenks but we can't use express easily in Electron so ... Maybe